# How to change size of an array-list to match the size of a given array-list in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I have two array lists which in different sizes, so I want to make the array list which is larger in size equal to smaller one size.

```
Double[] x = {
  14.2, 16.4, 11.9, 15.2, 18.5, 22.1, 19.4, 25.1, 23.4, 18.1, 22.6, 17.2
};
Double[] y = {
  17.5, 14.2, 12.2, 16.0, 19.3
};

ArrayList<Double> aListX = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(x));
ArrayList<Double> aListY = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(y));
```

I want ArrayList `aListX` as the same size as an ArrayList `aListY`

Result:

```
aListX.size() = 5
```

Comment: And what should be removed?

Comment: Looks like you need a [Thanos algorithm](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-algorithm-used-in-destroying-half-of-the-universe-by-the-Infinity-Gauntlet-used-by-Thanos-in-Avengers-Infinity-War-Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-I-mean-who-decides-who-will-die-and-who-lives)

Comment: Does it matter what values you remove from the bigger list? Or do you want to distribute the values across both lists?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson keep the first five elemets in this case

Comment: ArrayList<Double> aListX = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(x).subList(0, y.length));

Comment: @deHaar  keep the first five elemets in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it :)

```
    aListX = new ArrayList<>(aListX.subList(0, aListY.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can declare the list as a `List` instead of an `ArrayList`

```
List<Double> aListX
```

then you can do

```
aListX = aListX.subList(0, aListY.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator to remove element after 5th index

```
Iterator iterate = aListX.iterator();
int index = 0;
while (iterate.hasNext()) {
    iterate.next();
    if (index >= aListY.size()) {
        iterate.remove();
    }
    ++index;
}
```